# Alternative defaults with a different table name

Tags: postgresql, default-value

Say the original table has `DEFAULT nextval('some_sequence')`. I'm looking for a way to specify `DEFAULT nextval('another_sequence')` on a table view/alias so that I can just insert into the alias as usual instead of repeating `int_col = nextval('another_sequence')` with every insert. In other words, the user/application only needs to be concerned with a table name and not whichever sequence is being used. Is this possible?

Comment: A view with an `instead of trigger` comes to mind

Comment: Can you use a function to insert new values instead of an INSERT sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Found a clean solution thanks to a_horse_with_no_name for the idea and the syntax example set in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036336/4698922)

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_view AS
    SELECT * FROM tbl;

ALTER TABLE tbl_view ALTER int_col SET DEFAULT nextval('another_sequence');
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know you can have defaults on view columns.